# FOR ALL ENTRIES through empty itab selects all records from DB

Tags: abap, opensql

I have a query in which I am using `FOR ALL ENTRIES`. The internal table `lt_customer` has no records.

```
SELECT *
    FROM bsid
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_customer2
    FOR ALL ENTRIES IN lt_customer
    WHERE bukrs EQ p_bukrs
      AND belnr EQ lt_customer-belnr
      AND gjahr EQ lt_customer-gjahr.
```

Now, since `lt_customer` has no record, I am expecting a dump here. But it turns out that it was selecting all the records from `bsid` into `lt_customer2`. I don't understand why or how. Please enlighten me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the standard behaviour, as documented in the ABAP Help:

"If the internal table itab is empty, the entire WHERE condition is ignored."

https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenwhere_logexp_itab.htm

Check if the table is not empty before the SELECT:

```
IF lt_customer IS NOT INITIAL.
  SELECT ...
  ...
  FOR ALL ENTRIES IN lt_customer
  ...
ENDIF.
```

Comment: Thanks, due to the large volume of data, it throws dump bc of the memory allocation. thanks again!

Comment: @Kjarlvi It's a very frequent pitfall even seasoned ABAP programmers stumble into from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

FOR ALL ENTRIES working look like IN operator. If itab empty then this condition ignored. You need to make manual check or add dummy record to lt_customer.